# Car Suspension - Getting Contact Depth and Speed From rayCast()

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, physics

So I am making a vehicle physics wrapper for my game(aswell as one other game). I am doing kinda well with it, now I've gotten to suspension. And here I use simple method: I apply impulse downwards from each wheel equalient to it's load - that's the gravity. And I also apply impulse upwards from suspension.
I have found this link:
http://vehiclephysics.com/advanced/how-suspensions-work/
Where it's said that:

***F**suspension = **K**spring * **x** + **F**damper * **V**contact*

As you can notice already that springrate and damper force are constants. However, other 2 values are variables. I want to find out how to obtain contact depth(***x***) and contact speed(***V**contact*) from a ray that I cast from wheel joint position downwards(in -Z axis relative to car). I already obtain the distance how far the ray reach, but I need to find out the compression using this distance. And also I need a way to determine the speed of contact.

Thanks already now! :D

Comment: Hm... Maybe this isn't the right place for this question?:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! Here is the deal.
As I already told, I obtain the length of the contact ray already. I will not discuss it's obtanation here, it is just `rayCast()` method with some more math.
Now I do `suspension_length - ray_distance`.
This returns the contact depth or ***x*** value. To get the speed of it I make a property *exdepth* for my suspension and after the end of frame I store the depth(***x***) value into it. Than on start of frame I compare them like so: `x - exdepth` and than I get the contact speed value(***V**contact*).
And that's it - issue solved;)